# Why do I get a RuntimeError: cannot cache function 'extract_scaled' error with xarray-zonal in AWS lambda when it works locally

Tags: aws-lambda, python-xarray

This works locally but not through AWS Lambda. It is using xarray-spatial to generate some zonal stats

This takes data from an xarray data set and puts it through zonal_stats - normally, and locally, it produces a nice pandas dataframe. I know and appreciate how important code examples are on SO but there isn't much else I can show you as this feels like an AWS thing over a code issue thing.

```
def zonal(self, data_id, zonal_id):
        zs = zonal_stats(self.dataset[zonal_id], self.dataset[data_id])
        pixel_area = round(math.pow(self.dataset[data_id].attrs['pixel_length'],2),2)
        zs['area_ha'] = pixel_area * zs['count'] / 10000
        return zs
```

```
[ERROR] RuntimeError: cannot cache function 'extract_scaled': no locator available for file '/var/task/datashader/composite.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from data import Data
  File "/var/task/data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from xrspatial import zonal_stats
  File "/var/task/xrspatial/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xrspatial.aspect import aspect  # noqa
  File "/var/task/xrspatial/aspect.py", line 10, in <module>
    from xrspatial.utils import ArrayTypeFunctionMapping, cuda_args, ngjit, not_implemented_func
  File "/var/task/xrspatial/utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import datashader as ds
  File "/var/task/datashader/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .core import Canvas                                 # noqa (API import)
  File "/var/task/datashader/core.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import reductions as rd
  File "/var/task/datashader/reductions.py", line 13, in <module>
    from datashader.transfer_functions._cuda_utils import (cuda_atomic_nanmin,
  File "/var/task/datashader/transfer_functions/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from datashader.composite import composite_op_lookup, over, validate_operator
  File "/var/task/datashader/composite.py", line 30, in <module>
    def extract_scaled(x):
  File "/var/task/numba/core/decorators.py", line 212, in wrapper
    disp.enable_caching()
  File "/var/task/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 863, in enable_caching
    self._cache = FunctionCache(self.py_func)
  File "/var/task/numba/core/caching.py", line 613, in __init__
    self._impl = self._impl_class(py_func)
  File "/var/task/numba/core/caching.py", line 350, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("cannot cache function %r: no locator available "
```

Comment: I'd guess the issue is different environments with different versions of the packages you're using. Did you install the env? maybe check the package versions against the ones you have installed locally and try to isolate the differences. also - is this being run on a distributed cluster? or just a single server?

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado - thank you so much for the reply. This is a docker-ized lambda so the packages, from my undestanding, should all be identical as it is built locally and then uploaded. I will keep picking away at it today to see if there is anything else but this is the only change that has been introduced.